# Which datatype can be used for storing HTML files in database?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I want to store a webpage in `Sql Server`. The page may contain images and other stuff. What data type should I use? As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx),  *ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in the future versions of `SQL Server`*. What data type can be used to store `HTML` files which have different stuff like images and things like `JavaScript` codes?

Comment: In general `nvarchar(MAX)` if you want to store it in text format and `varbinary(MAX)` if you want to store it in binary format - these are the official "successors" of `ntext` and `image`. How do you plan to include the images? Are they embedded as data URLs or do you need to store them separately in the DB as well?

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, that is my question too. I do not know how images can be stored If I use `nvarchar(max)` and whether they can be retrieved correctly or not

Comment: Firstly, if you plan to stored images as part of your HTML file, you need to convert them to base64 so they are textual and not binary. Second, and since your are talking about sql-server then NVARCHAR(MAX) is the way to go.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly, what you *actually* want to save is not a `html` file but a *webpage*, which consists of a `html` file plus some images, right? If that is the case, have you considered just storing it in the file system and storing just the path in the DB?

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, I am doing that. Is that wrong to store the webpage inside the database?

Comment: Not wrong, both have advantages and disadvantages (see [this discussion, for example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3748/87698)). If you decide to store them in the DB, `nvarchar(MAX)` for the HTML text and `varbinary(MAX)` for the images are the appropriate data type.

Comment: What's the *purpose* in storing it in the DB? Is the DB just acting as dumb storage, or are you planning to perform some processing within the database? If the latter, describe what type(s) of processing are meant to take place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I want to make a search engine to search the static pages. I have to supply webpages for `DB` to a `C#` program

Comment: So, if we focus on *just the database part*, it's just acting as dumb storage? You're not expecting to write SQL that can pull out, say, all `<h1>` headings. All of that sort of work will be done by application(s).

Comment: yes. @Damien_The_Unbeliever So I should store them or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to store both the HTML of the web page as well as the images, you might want to consider storing the images in the file system instead. Here is a comparison of the advantages and disadvantages of both options:

- [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3748/87698)

---

If you decide to store them in the DB, the appropriate data types are:

- `nvarchar(MAX)` for the HTML text and
- `varbinary(MAX)` for the images.

Answer (score 2):

I could store them in the DB, by

using `nvarchar(MAX)`. it has stored the data as well as retrieved data with the image.

My objective was to copy and paste emails received. These emails can have HTML tags and can also have images. I tried it with `nvarchar(max)` and it worked.

I am using VB6 as a development tool. The only problem I found was I could not store it with stored procedures passing the values through addParameter.

I have stored it with traditional saving mechanism from VB6

```
With Recordset<br>
 .addnewM<br>
 .Fields("MailBody")<br>
 .Update<br>
End With<br>
```

If anyone gets idea of storing using the stored procedure, let me know